# jQuery Toggle, when new menu opens, close the

Tags: jquery, menu, toggle

I have multiple menus (forms) with visibility hidden and I open them with a clickevent on an icon. It all works well, exept when I open another menu when the former menu is still open, they both stay visible. So, i want the fomer menu to hide when a new one is opening.

HTML

```
<span id='settingsIcon' class='settingsIcon'>S
    <div class='settingForms'>
        <div class='formMoveButton'>
            <span class='settingsMakePublicIcon'>w</span>
            <form action='' method='post' class='moveForm'>
                <input class='settingsMakePublicButton' type='submit' value='Make public        ' name='$this->move'/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</span>
```

jQuery

```
$(".settingsIcon").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();

    if($(document).find(".settingForms").is(':visible') < 1) {
        HandleSettingsWindow($($(this).children()[0]));
    } else {
    }
});

HandleSettingsWindow = function (el) {
    $(document).click(function () { // Close the menu when clicked outside it
        el.hide();
        document.oncontextmenu = function () { return true; };
    });
    el.toggle();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this please: http://jsfiddle.net/RttT5/

**Note** `if($(document).find(".settingForms").is(':visible'))`

Hope rest fits your needs `:)`

**Code**

```
$(".settingsIcon").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();

    if($(document).find(".settingForms").is(':visible')) {
        HandleSettingsWindow($($(this).children()[0]));
    } else {

    }
});

HandleSettingsWindow = function (el) {
    $(document).click(function () { // Close the menu when clicked outside it
        el.hide();
        document.oncontextmenu = function () { return true; };
    });
    el.toggle();
}​
```

Comment: I don't really follow you on what to do next though, that's what I'm struggling with. If it is any visible menus on the page, i want to close them when opening a new one.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with this line

```
if($(document).find(".settingForms").is(':visible') < 1)
```

there is no need for the < 1, you can just use

```
if($(document).find(".settingForms").is(':visible'))
```